# Parallel asynchronous requests in SOA using a messaging broker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, soa, rpc

I've been looking at an SOA using a messaging broker (rabbitmq / rails), however there are still a few niggles I cant get my head around.

If I wanted to run parallel requests as you would using something like [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) with http

a) how in an asynchronous system like this - when you have potentially multiple threads publishing to the same topic exchange do you connect the response message with your request - would you add a unique routing key?

c) what would be the best way initiating and managing multiple parallel calls of this nature in ruby?

Many thanks

Comment: What happened to b) ?

Comment: rogue typo  :/ would change now, but lads have adapted their answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to a), yes you use a routing key, or in the parlance of messaging, a [*correlation identifier*](http://www.eaipatterns.com/CorrelationIdentifier.html).

In answer to c), sorry I haven't a clue about Ruby, but messaging by nature supports parallelism by using queues to manage throughput. I assume that whatever broker you choose would provide the appropriate samples and tooling for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would use at sidekiq or rescue for jobs like that. If your system is larger and distributed you can create a module/class which takes your job including key as argument, sends it to rabbitmq, some worker which is subscribed to fan out or channel picks it up and sends the result back as POST to your app (web hook approach).

For simplicity you can also just put some sort of Ajax spinner on your view and poll every 10 seconds or whatever suits you if the result is back. For sure you should have some kind of id for every job. If you have questions about it I could elaborate more. My apps crunch a lot if data in long running tasks with up to 500,000,000 items in rabbit queues.